# Is there any known nontrivial result on QIP systems having a space-bounded verifier?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, quantum-computing, space-bounded, interactive-proofs

Is there any known nontrivial result on quantum interactive proof (QIP) systems having a space-bounded verifier?

The only paper I know is [An application of quantum finite automata to interactive proof systems](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000008001165) by Nishimura and Yamakami, in which a restricted 2QFA (two-way quantum finite automaton) model is used as a verifier and the following result is given: 
$ \mathsf{QIP(2qfa,polytime)} \subseteq \mathsf{NP} $.

The motivation: I am preparing a paper containing some new results on space-bounded QIP systems and I want to be sure not missing any related known result!

Comment: Do you know what happens when you restrict an IP system to have a space-bounded verifier? That might be a good place to start.

Comment: @Robin: Yes, I am aware many of the classical results. In fact, I am preparing a paper containing some new results on space-bounded QIP systems and I want to be sure not missing any related known result!